# -하느라 하지 말고 Meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, north-korean

I've been reading some Northern texts and came across this -하느라 하지 말고 phrase being used. I'm unsure what it means or how to understand it. Some examples of its use:

내 말은 덮어놓고 여름부터 땀흘리며 일**하느라 하지 말고** 겨울철먹이를 구해먹는 짐승들과 집안에 앉아서 먹기만 하는 짐승들이 두패로 갈라져 겨울채비를 하자는겁니다.

이번 크리스마스 때는 아마도 집에서 홈 파티를 해야 할것같은데 번거롭게 이것저것 음식 **하느라 하지 말고** 고기는 서정FMB 폭립을 간단히 데워서 준비해야겠어요.

Answer (score 0):

'-느라 하지말고' is a kind of northern dialect, but seems to be used occasionally in the middle and southern parts of the Korean peninsula.

The meaning is just the same as '-하지 말고' or can be interpreted as '-하느라 고생하지 말고.'
Thus '땀흘리며 일하느라 하지 말고' is same as '땀흘리며 일하지 말고' or '땀흘리며 일하느라 고생하지 말고.'

Answer (score 0):

As a Korean, it sounds weird to me. I don't think it is standard language,I think many Koreans cannot understand it. It would be good to ignore it.

https://www.rfa.org/korean/weekly_program/bd81d55c-itc640-acfcd559ae30c220/sciencetech-02052021095828.html

In this link, North Korean 김흥광 박사 says 하느라 하지 말고, but... it's just weird. You don't have to analyze it deeply.